# Wireless monitor

Tags: wireless-networking, display

Is there such a thing?

Ideally, I'd hook up some device onto my VGA/DVI jack on the computer and some other device to the same jack on the monitor and the data would flow wirelessly.

Comment: should be "wireless display"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NewEgg carries the [IOGear Wireless Audio / Video Kit](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815290011). (Or [without the audio](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815290008))

> Iogear presents a wireless High
>   Definition multimedia enjoyment
>   solution to you with its Wireless
>   Audio / Video Kit! Connect the USB
>   adapter to your PC, the VGA adapter to
>   your VGA display and audio adapter to
>   your speakers, and voila!
>
> Enjoy all the multimedia content
>   stored on your computer through your
>   home theater system! No complex cables
>   to tangle and clutter your living
>   room!
>
> [image]

They also carry the [Addlogix Wireless Video Display Adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812211002). Amusingly enough, you can use an ethernet cable to run the signal (making it not so wireless):

> Send signal wirelessly to your
>   projector or TV with the addlogix
>   EV2100 wireless display adapter. It
>   takes advantage of your 802.11b/g
>   connection to send a signal to your TV
>   or projector. You can also run an
>   Ethernet cable for the signal.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work:  [IOGear Wireless USB to VGA Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001KEDMNC)

Comment: Note, this is the *vga adapter only* - you still need the USB unit for the host PC: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815290010