# What are current solutions for wireless display (Dvi connections or WiFi)?

Tags: wireless-networking, dvi

Related:

[Is there any device/adapter that allows connecting DVI or HDMI display over Wi-Fi or Bluetooth?](https://superuser.com/q/371490/404747)

[Wireless monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/72890/wireless-monitor/72900#72900)

---

- The [WiDi solution](https://superuser.com/a/371501/404747) looked promising, but it appears to require specific devices or hardware - while I already have my PC and Monitor.
- Many solutions here or on Google seem to require large several-hundred dollar boxes which are senders/receivers (or aren't really wireless at all, but just use a cat5 cable) - but I'd really like to keep it small and simple on both ends. I'm wondering if I'm looking at outdated equipment - since everything I find seems to be about 3 years old.
- My monitor is nothing special, just has DVI inputs

---

My use case is that I have my PC and Monitor, and often like to move where I'm at in the house. For instance, I often like to game upstairs if I'm with friends online, but downstairs if I'm gaming with others in the house. In the summer, my upstairs also tends to get hot - so I'd prefer if I could keep my PC somewhere where it can stay cooler even if my monitor has to suffer the heat. I will also bring my PC and monitor to other places at times, and having one less cord to worry about would be nice.

A laptop would make more sense, but in reality I don't have the money to spend for a laptop, especially since I would prefer to use my desktop most of the time. This is also why the several-hundred dollar boxes I'm seeing online are not a good solution for me. That being said, if the solution requires a monitor or HDTV with specific features I may also consider something which works over a local wireless network.

---

Are there currently somewhat cheap (less than $80 USD) solutions for a wireless display with enough distance where I don't have to be in the same room? The best device would be discrete, cheap, and have good distance.

Comment: Have you ever done gaming on a USB display (a display whose only input is USB; no VGA, no HDMI, no DVI)? Were you okay with the resolution, frame rate, and compression artifacts of that? I ask because wireless data rates are usually less than USB 2.0 Hi-Speed, so no wireless display solution is going to be better quality than a USB display. I hear most gamers who've tried USB displays hate gaming on them, so bear that in mind.

Comment: @Spiff I haven't done gaming off a USB display. If its fairly cheap I may try  something with low quality. I'm also going to edit my question just a little - perhaps a newer monitor (or HDTV) that can connect to my local network may provide alternatives.

Comment: Using a Raspberry Pi or some similar device connected to the display and using VNC (Teamviewer?) to replicate your computer display would be cheap and usable for most of applications were a little latency is not an issue… But that won't do the trick for gaming. As written by Spiff and as far as I know there's no cheap magic available yet for heavy requirements linked to modern gaming.

Comment: @yoann-h That sounds like it could be an answer rather than a comment

Comment: Indeed. Converted.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Raspberry Pi or some similar device connected to the display and using VNC (Teamviewer?) to replicate your computer display would be cheap and usable for most of applications were a little latency is not an issue… But that won't do the trick for gaming. As written by Spiff and as far as I know there's no cheap magic available yet for heavy requirements linked to modern gaming.

Comment: Accepting until proved otherwise ;)

Comment: I hope it will!